# Issue with handling two responses from two different ajax calls

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have an issue in my module i am mapping two responses(arrays) from two different ajax calls,so that i got a total response of two ajax calls as single array.Here I have to use that total response out of the angular for each loop to post some of the properties.But due to for each loops the object is posted repeatedly.
Here is my code:

```
 $scope.fnGetDetails = function(uniqueId) {
        $scope.uniqueId = uniqueId.jdDetails.uniqueId;
        angular.forEach($scope.aIdResponse, function(value, key) {
            console.log(value.jdDetails.uniqueId);
            if (value.jdDetails.uniqueId == $scope.uniqueId) {
                $scope.jdList = value.recruiter;
            }
        });
        $scope.aRecPush = [];
        $scope.aSelectedPush = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.jdList, function(value, key) {
            interviewStatusService.fnGetRecruiterDetails($scope.uniqueId, value).then(function(response) {
                $scope.recResponse = response;
                if ($scope.aRecPush.indexOf($scope.recResponse) === -1) {
                    $scope.aRecPush.push($scope.recResponse);

                }

                $scope.aRecVar = $scope.aRecPush;
            });
            interviewStatusService.fnGetSelectedProfiles($scope.uniqueId, value).then(function(response) {
                $scope.aRes = response;
                $scope.aLength = $scope.aRes.length;
                if ($scope.aSelectedPush.indexOf($scope.aLength) === -1) {
                    $scope.aSelectedPush.push($scope.aLength);
                    $scope.aSelectedVar = $scope.aSelectedPush;
                    $scope.mappedData = $scope.aRecVar.map(function(value, index) {
                        return {
                            data: value,
                            value: $scope.aSelectedVar[index]
                        }


                    });

                }

                angular.forEach($scope.mappedData, function(value, key) {
                    interviewStatusService.fnPostRecruiterTrack(value.data[0].recruiter, value.data[0].length, value.data[0].uniqueId, value.value).then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                });


            });
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please describe your problem in more details, I'm not sure that I understood it.